# How do I Create Multiple Headers with ColumnSpans in a WPF GridView?

Tags: wpf, gridview, formatting

I want to "group" some columns in a WPF GridView by having an additional header row that spans a couple of the columns in the GridView.

In ASP.Net with a repeater this would look like:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater">
    <HeaderTemplate>
       <table>
       <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td colspan="2">Group 1</td>
          <td colspan="2">Group 2</td>
          <td></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Value 1 Header</td>
          <td>Value 2 Header</td>
          <td>Value 3 Header</td>
          <td>Value 4 Header</td>
          <td>Value 5 Header</td>
          <td>Value 6 Header</td>
       </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
       <tr>
          <td>Value 1</td>
          <td>Value 2</td>
          <td>Value 3</td>
          <td>Value 4</td>
          <td>Value 5</td>
          <td>Value 6</td>
       </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
       </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

So the "Value 1" would just have the one header, while "Value 2" and "Value 3" would have a header and a grouping header above that.

Any thoughts on how to do this type of thing in WPF?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have done this using DataGrid in Wpf, Here is the sample:

```
    <toolkit:DataGrid x:Name="dgValue" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
            <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <Grid Width="150">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Item"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="SubItem1"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="SubItem2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Width="150">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SubItem1}" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding SubItem2}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
    </toolkit:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Looks good, but you seem to have to define the width of the columns?  I was hoping (like in ASP.net) that you could have all the column widths be dynamic.  If you leave off the width it looks like it might not lineup correctly then?  Or am I reading that wrong?

Comment: There is a similar answer available [on MSDN for a "super header"](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/1e414159-70f6-4be3-9be5-56e4f3278366).

Comment: Is there anything similar for GridView and not DataGrid?